# When doing [load More] should we put the latest found records on top of the accumulated list?

Tags: user-behavior

Let say you load customer name from DB to client. You adopt the [Load More] approach. When u click [Load More] the system will get new records from DB & add into the accumulated Customer Name List.

Just wondering should we put the latest found records on **TOP** of the accumulated list?

Or should we put the latest found records on **BOTTOM** of the accumulated list?

Which one make user more happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the user scrolls to the bottom, looking at all visible records, and then wants to load more.  So typically, the "Load More" button is at the bottom of the list, and new records appear at the bottom.

Comment: that'make sense, thax u very much